# .htaccess for nexcess shared hosting

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, .htaccess, hosting

I have 2 sites running on different shared hosting servers with nexcess.net both with similar setups (same version of EE 2.6.1 and same add-ons) and both experiencing different issues which I'm begining to think are .htaccess related.

I am using the EE recomended .htaccess rule to remove the index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The index.php is being removed on both sites.

The first site is having an issue with Assets (2.1.4) loading the sites home page in the assets modal window when I go to add file. It is causing the following error in the server log.

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I have double checked the file upload preferences (Standard file manager is working without issue). 
File upload folders have permissions 0f 777. 
EE Cache folder is 777.
I've tried adding $config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php'; to config file
Php memory limit is set to 512mb in php.ini

On the second site Assets is running fine but the client is reporting that when editing channel entries EE is not saving the entry intermittently and just returning to the admin homepage.  Not sure if this is related but could possibly be.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried removing (or renaming) the .htaccess temporarily to test whether its' the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the main index.php file got renamed. As you could guess this would cause a multitude of problems. With there being no front end templates at this early stage I incorrectly suspected the .htaccess was causing the problem with the paths.

Thanks for the input Tyssen and Steven.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried on Nexcess but my goto htaccess is

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Looks for files and directories that do not exist
# and provide the segments to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```